# Gridview cell value and array list

Tags: asp.net

When I am tryng to pass the gridview cell values to an array everything is perfect but the array is empty after executing the code.

When I see through debug mode the index of selected row also is fine, i.e. when I select two rows using checkbox among 1000 the count shows exactly 2 in the array but the data is empty.

I'm not able to get the cell value from the gridview.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
protected void Button2008_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   ArrayList checkedItems = new ArrayList(); 

   foreach (GridViewRow row in this.GridView1.Rows) 
   {
      if (((CheckBox)row.FindControl("cbRows")).Checked == true) 
      {
         checkedItems.Add(row.Cells[12].Text);
      } 
   }

   Session["CheckedItems"] = checkedItems; 

   Response.Redirect("About.aspx", true); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a breakpoint and check where the problem is occuring, for instance, does `row.Cells[12].Text` show any value ?

and you can check how your aspx page is acting after the postback.

Comment: double that. Probably the 12 index is incorrect or empty. Remeber the Cells collection is ZERO based .